# Creating a (moveable) grid

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to create a movable/scalable grid? I currently use JQuery and Raphael, but I want to keep it as small as possible. My current method works as follows:

On each move/resize:
 - Calculate width/height
 - Remove all previous gridlines
 - Create (Width / Grid size) vertical lines (SVG)
 - Create (Height / Grid size) horizontal lines (SVG)

Is there a more effective way?

Comment: Is this like a table? Is the whole thing moveable, or are the interior pieces re-arrangeable(?)? Can you put a sample in a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Czech this out: http://blog.hjoseph.com/post/432710318/griddie-a-javascript-grid-tool-for-web-development

I'm not sure if it has all of the features you want, but I came across this post by looking for a similar thing.